# Reboot remote system without using shutdown.exe

Tags: windows-xp

In Windows XP, is there a way to reboot a remote system without using shutdown.exe?

Target system is also Windows XP, and access via RDP is available.  I do have local administrative privileges on the box, but for some reason can't run shutdown.exe.

I know certain tasks such as logoff and others can be done with rundll32, but I'm not sure what (if any) the syntax would be to use it for shutdown or reboot.

Comment: Try shutdown /? that solved all my questions about this ;)

Comment: @Michael The title says "without using shutdown.exe" ;)

Comment: oh, sorry for that, my thoughts were blocked a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can run shutdown from your *own* machine, so it shouldn't matter if it's available on the remote machine or not.

```
shutdown \\computername /r /t:5 "Your computer is shutting down in 5 seconds. Bye." /y /f
```

/r is for reboot
/t:X is "Shutdown in X seconds"
/y is "Answer yes to everything"
/f is "Force"

Comment: Far as I know, this still requires permissions to execute the command on the remote computer - which for some odd reason I seem to lack.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, there was a remote terminal shutdown utility in windows 2000 that might work on win XP. It's called TSSHUTDN. There is also a sysinternals tool called Psshutdown. I've added in some Google results below.

[Windows KB Article on it](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=320188)

[XP Pro Documentation Hosted by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_tsshutdn.mspx?mfr=true)

[Tech net article talking about different shutdown tools](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/02/09/two-minute-drill-shutdown-exe-tsshutdn-exe-and-psshutdown-exe.aspx)

I have not tested any of these solutions.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can reboot the computer by creating and running this VBScript on the remote computer:

```
set objwmiservice = getobject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}\\.\root\cimv2") 
set coloperatingsystems = objwmiservice.execquery ("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem") 
for each objoperatingsystem in coloperatingsystems 
    objoperatingsystem.Win32Shutdown(2) 
next
```

[Script source](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ad9cf30f-5f9a-406c-bba1-7c30388c1adb), [Win32Shutdown documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)